# I can't change my preferred graphics card on my notebook

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, nvidia-geforce

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Z570 with an Intel i5 processor, 4 GB RAM, and an NVIDIA GT 520 GPU.
And I can't select my preferred graphics card nor change the graphics card for my applications.

[image]

I tried with Lenovo drivers and the latest drivers from Intel and NVIDIA sites, but I have the same problem with all of these drivers.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Look at the front left corner of the laptop. There's a switch. Turn it on. Now your graphics card is enabled and you can finally enjoy proper gaming.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lenovo ideapad y570, and my card doesn't want to activate while I play the secret world ? if someone can find a solution, It is written that the nvidia is for that game, but it doesn't work ingame...